# Добавление строки в таблицу

Tags: php, phalcon, mvc

В общем Phalcon - фреймворк. Мне нужно зарегистрировать пользователя. В контроллере я пишу:

```
//AuthController.php
Users::add($this->login,$this->password)
```

Users - это объект модели, функция add содержит следующее:

```
//Users.php
public function add($login,$password){
$this->login = $login;
$this->password = $this->security->hash($password);
return $this->save();
}
```

В этом случаи вылетает ошибка

> Call to undefined method AuthController::save()

Хотя метод save по идее должен вызываться из класса Users, а вернее из его родителя \Phalcon\Mvc\Model. В документации по фреймворку добавление пользователя реализовано в контроллере, таким образом:

```
$users = new Users();
$users->login = $login;
$users->password = $password;
$users->save();
```

Но я считаю, что это не совсем правильно с точки зрения MVC. Мне кажется само добавление должно быть в моделе. Да и потом проще, не нужно писать эти строки, а просто Users::add, например, когда буду делать админку. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать, чтобы сохранение производилось в моделе? Или может я не прав, и добавление в моделе делают только днища?

Comment: а как у вас получилось, что $this не указывает на модель ? я фалькон не щупал, но по идее при статических функциях, там должно быть что-то типа self:: (если я правильно понимаю, там синглтон)

Comment: Пробовал self, ошибка: 
Fatal error: Non-static method Phalcon\Mvc\Model::save() cannot be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in ((( Я так понимаю ошибка подразумевает запрет вызова метода save изнутри?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в контроллере AuthController вызываете метод save(). Как Вы сами пишите:

> Но я считаю, что это не совсем правильно с точки зрения MVC.

Может быть Вы неправильно считаете? С точки зрения MVC модель осуществляет работу с БД, а не контроллер.
Вы должны вызвать модель Users и тогда уже вызвать метод save. В документации все правильно сказано.
Просто таким кодом Вы получается задаете контроллеру с его переменными login и password значения из модели, в данной случае Users, и вызываете в контроллере метод save(), как было сказано.

Comment: Да, скорее всего Вы правы. Понял теперь, спасибо))